# Difference between declaring object as its superclass and its class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I've read through the inheritance section of my java book and I tried the following example as practice:

```
public class Car {
private int wheels;
private int doors;
public Car(int initWheels, int initDoors){
    wheels = initWheels;
    doors = initDoors;
}
public int getWheels(){
    return  wheels;
}
public int getDoors(){
    return doors;
}

protected int calculateMaterials(){
    return wheels + doors;
}
}
```

---

```
public class Ford extends Car{
private String color;
private String type;
private int horsePower;
public Ford(int initWheels, int initDoors, String initColor, String initType, int initHorsePower){
    super(initWheels, initDoors);
    color = initColor;
    type = initType;
    horsePower = initHorsePower;
}
public String getColor(){
    return color;
}
public String getType(){
    return type;
}

protected int calculateMaterials(){
    return getWheels() + getDoors() + horsePower;
}
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Car car = new Car(4,4);
    Car myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
    System.out.println(myCar.getWheels());
    System.out.println(myCar.calculateMaterials());
  }
}
```

However after re-looking at the code I came to question my-self if this was possible: `Car myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);` . . . I ran it and saw that the output was exactly the same and now I am wondering if this:

```
Car myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
```

and this

```
Ford myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
```

the same thing, if so which was is preferable or more common? If not how come I get the same output?

Comment: Car class constructor only has 2 arguments, yet in your example you are passing it 5, which matches the Ford class. This wouldn't compile.

Comment: did you get to the [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) part?

Comment: I agree with Samhain… are you absolutely sure that new Car(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2) really works?

Comment: @rec no it doesn't, I changed it though. Typed it wrong.

Comment: @user2895567 based on your edit, the result of calling myCar.calculateMaterials() should be 6+2+2, or 10.

Comment: @user2895567, ok, then I suppose the answer I was trying to give first is indeed applicable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declare the reference type as `Car` You would get what I think is the desired result from

```
Ford myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
```

Several people bring up the good point that you are not actually overloading the constructor. That is really the larger problem here. Overloading the constructor only truly happens when you have the same arguments for the constructor of both the top class and the inheriting class. As a result you are always calling the Ford Constructor whenever you include five arguments

Comment: This is not correct.  Creating two classes with inheritance that have the same function name, the JVM will invoke the correct version based on the class type that was instantiated, NOT based on the type of the variable(Car vs Ford).

Comment: @Samhain I think I edited to reference what you are getting at. if not please explain cause I am interested

Comment: Lets suppose he actually created code that compiled( both Card and Ford  have constructors with 5 arguments ).  `Car myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2); myCar.calculateMaterials();` would call the Ford implementation of calculateMaterials while `Car myCar = new Car(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2); myCar.calculateMaterials();` would call the Car implementation of calculateMaterials.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot Not really. User gets the same output because the correct the correct `calculateMaterials` will be called, e.g., whether the variable is *declared* a `Car` or a `Ford`, the `Ford` class's `calculateMaterials` will be called. Which is kind of the point.

Comment: @DaveNewton correct, I assume he's meaning between two different runs of the code( once as new Car, once as new Ford ).  Now that he's corrected the post, maybe he should post both runs and results?

Comment: @DaveNewton Basically what you are saying is that any time there are five arguments in such a case the JVM will automatically create it as a ford?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot I'm not saying anything like that. *You* told it to create it as a `Ford`, because you're *calling* `new Ford(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same output because `car` is a reference of type of `Car` not `Ford`. As a result, you cannot pass the `Ford`'s methods to the reference `car` because it's reference type is `Car` not `Ford`. Therefore, to get what you want, you have to change the reference type of the reference variable `car` to `Ford` such as:

```
Ford fordCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
```

But, this: `Car myCar = new Car(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);` should not compile at all, because the `Car` constructor does not have the 5 argument constructor defined in `Car`

Comment: `Car fordCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);` this works as well though so how are they different?

Comment: @user2895567 Because you can't call `Ford`-specific functions on `fordCar`, because a `Ford` is-a `Car`, but a `Car` is-not-a `Ford`.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb:

- within a method, use the type which you need (if you need Ford-specific stuff, use Ford, otherwise Car)
- in a return value of a function, use the same type you used in the method
- when passing a value as a parameter, use the type you need in the parameter declaration, e.g. print(Car car) if you want to use only Car-specific stuff, otherwise print(Ford ford) if you need Ford-specific stuff

Answer (score 0):

> which was is preferable or more common?

It depends on how you intend to use the reference.  If the methods necessary are only specific to something of type `Car`, then the reference should be declared as such.  However, if you will need to get details associated with a subclass (`Ford` in your example), then that is the type that should be declared.  In other words, always use the *least* specific type necessary.

> If not how come I get the same output?

Because you are using the values only associated with type `Car` in both cases.  If you don't add any more type-specific information to `Ford` then it probably shouldn't be it's own type.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following example will print 8, 10, and 10.  The instantiation of the object(new) is what tells the JVM which code to run, not the type.  In this example, myCar and myCarToo are both instantiated as type Ford, even though they are stored in variabled typed as Car and Ford.

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Car car = new Car(6,2);
    Car myCar = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);
    Ford myCarToo = new Ford(6,2,"black", "pickup", 2);

    System.out.println(car.calculateMaterials());  //Car.calculateMaterials
    System.out.println(myCar.calculateMaterials());  //Ford.calculateMaterials
    System.out.println(myCarToo.calculateMaterials());  //Ford.calculateMaterials
  }
}
```